# How to structure the HTML in order to use a POST request instead of GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

The logout button in the view file looks like this:

```
<a href="/logout" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark right-button">Log out</a>
```

Logout GET request in app.js looks like this and works just fine:

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

I'd like to switch to POST request like this for logout:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next){
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

But I keep getting this browser error: Cannot GET /logout. What do I need to change for the POST request to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change a link to a submit button in a form with POST action.

```
<form action="/logout" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do I have to use a <form> tag for POST requests?

Comment: If you want to stay as close as possible to original HTML concepts, then yes. Alternatively, you can customize everything with JavaScript, including sending POST requests with links.

Comment: Just to add: on the server, reply to the form submission with the HTML page to show after logout (or a redirect to it?).